# Logging out of a flask application is not revoking the authentication token

Tags: api, flask, flask-restful, flask-security

I am making an app in flask.

```
@app.route("/home")
@login_required
@auth_required("token")
def home():
  return "You are logged in", current_user.email

@app.route("/manual_logout")
@login_required
@auth_required("token")
def manual_logout():

  if request.method == "GET":
    logout_user()
    return "method GET logged you out"

  if request.method == "POST":
    logout_user()
    return "method POST logged you out"
```

I am logging in using the flask's `/login` endpoint . It is returning an authentication token. After logging in I call the home API, It successfully shows `You are logged in and current user's email`.

When i logout either using `/manual_logout` or `/logout`, The authentication token is still valid and I can still see the current users email.

I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you share the `logout_user()` funtion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record - Flask doesn't have a /login - I assume you are using Flask-Login and Flask-Security (always good to put in which versions as well).

However - you are correct - auth_tokens aren't revoked on logout - logout_user really just handles invalidating the session cookie. Use of auth_token for authorization is meant more for scripting etc - you really shouldn't use that for a browser-based application.

In Flask-Security-Too - you can set the TTL of an auth token, and by default, if you change your password, existing sessions and auth_tokens will be revoked.